# R: How to use multiple GPUs with XGBoost?

Tags: r, xgboost

I'm using xgboost to train my model. I expirienced that training with xgboost on GPU is much faster. Since I have 2 GPUs avaiable, I'd like to use both. Actually I have three questions about this topic.

#### How can I use multiple GPUs at the same time?

When running [this example](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/demo/gpu_accelerated.R) only the first GPU would work. I tried to set `gpu_id = 1`. That worked well, i.e. the other GPU did the job. Then I read that `gpu_id = -1` would provide the solution. Apparently this argument doesn't work with CUDA 10. I also tried `n_gpus` but that seems to be deprecated.

#### How can I clear the cache of GPU memory when finished?

This becomes important when I get to tune the parameters in some kind of a loop. A single model fits well into memory, but not hundreds.

#### R would crash, when I change the `gpu_id` for the next model. Is there a way to prevent this?

---

My setup:

- R version 3.4.4
- Ubuntu 18.04.3
- xgboost_1.0.0.1
- CUDA 10.2

Comment: have you had any luck so far with these issues?

Answer (score 1):

```
tree_method = 'gpu_hist',
n_gpus = -1
```

works for me with CUDA 10.2 and xgboost 0.90 in python.